# Organize buttons in android layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am using `LinearLayout` to design my `fragment`.

I want to add buttons to my layout and when it to reach to the end of the line, I want to add a line break and continue in line bottom.

How can I do it?

[image: Fourth element it is ok]

[image: I want to put the fifth element to the next line]

Comment: use `RecyclerView` or `GridView`

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you to use `TableLayout`,or else `GridView`

```
<TableLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:stretchColumns="1"
    android:shrinkColumns="0"
    >
    <TableRow>
        <Button android:id="@+id/title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            />
        <Button android:id="@+id/date"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            />
            ..................
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Comment: `GridView` should be better